# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout - Sections as columns

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building a UICollectionView in iOS 13 using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with 2 sections.

I want each section to be it's own column. Is this possible with
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

**My code:**

```
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionNumber, _ in
  let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
    heightDimension: .estimated(44)
  ))
  let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
      heightDimension: .estimated(44)
    ),
    subitem: item,
    count: 1
  )
  let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
  section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [
    NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: .estimated(38)
      ),
      elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
      alignment: .top
    )
  ]
  section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0)
  return section
})
```

**What it currently looks like:**

[image]

**What I want it to look like:**

[image]